# Is there any way to call a function in a separate js file for jquery click() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a confetti animation to play when a `button` is clicked. Is it possible to add a function from a separate JS file in the argument of `click`?

For example,

```
$('#test').click(
  // function in separate test.js file
);
```

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it will work? (the answer is yes)

Comment: As long as script `a` and script `b` are loaded, then yes

Comment: The very fact that you can use jQuery, a function within a separate javascript file, should answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function do not accepts arguments, You can use:

```
 $("#test").click(funcName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this. But presume if you export the function in another js file you can use require to reference it.

```
const anotherJS = require ("js_file_name")

$('#test').click( anotherJS.funcname);
```

Hope it helps